# How to fetch and display Nagios service thresholds in Alert mails

Tags: nagios

I need to show the service threshold values (-w ARG1 and -c ARG2) for `WARNING` and `CRITICAL` state in the alert mail body.

Along with the `SERVICESTATE` and `SERVICEOUTPUT` mail recipients will get better understanding on what exactly is the threshold set for the service.

Tried following line in the mail body of commands.conf file. `"Service threshold for WARNING at $ARG1$ and CRITICAL at $ARG$"` It didnt work. Please help with any means to fetch the threshold values.

Note: All Hosts and Services are monitored via NRPE host agent with commands and thresholds mentioned in the local nrpe.conf file. Nagios version: 4.3 core

Answer (score 1):

The values `$ARG1$` and so on are passed to the check command.  I don't believe there is a way for the notify command to access them.  The arguments the notify command receives come from the `service_notification_command` or `host_notification_command` value.

One way to achieve your goal should be to define a custom variable in the host/service, e.g.

```
define service {
  service_description MyCheck
  ...
  _CWARN 5
  _CCRITICAL 10
}
```

Note the preceding underscore.

This variable is then accessible using the macros `$_SERVICECWARN$` and `$_SERVICECCRITICAL$` (or `$_HOSTCWARN$` and `$_HOSTCCRITICAL$` for a host object).

You can also refer to these macros in your check command rather than `$ARG1$` etc. so that you don't need to update values in two places.